# OnMarkerClick events fires multiple times

Tags: c#, winforms, gmap.net

I try to popup a messagebox when the marker was left-clicked. When the marker was clicked, the event was fired, the popup was showing, but it fires multiple times (2 times).

This is my code

```
private void gmap_mainMap_OnMarkerClick(GMapMarker item, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left && item.IsMouseOver){
        MessageBox.Show("Marker clicked", "Information");
    }
}
```

Anyone have idea why the event keeps firing multiple times? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just to make sure, you can do this:

```
private bool MarkerWasClicked = false;

private void gmap_mainMap_OnMarkerClick(GMapMarker item, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    MarkerWasClicked = false;

    if (MarkerWasClicked == false){
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left && item.IsMouseOver){
            MessageBox.Show("Marker clicked", "Information");
            MarkerWasClicked = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your solution. I try to do some changes in my code that can match your solution, and it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When does your code subscribe to the event? Multiple firing could indicate the lack of unsubscribing of events. Are you unsubscribing from the event?

[Read here about unsubscribing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/events/how-to-subscribe-to-and-unsubscribe-from-events#unsubscribing), not doing so can lead to other undesired effects within your code. While the proposed solution solves your issue for the short term, I'd encourage you to look into the problem a little more to prevent future issues.

Comment: I tried using both Properties and Programatically to subscribe my event. When I subscribe programatically, I subs my event in the form's constructor.  I tried to unsubs my event after the MouseClick event end (using the -= operator) and I can't click my marker afterwards.